# $X$ is locally the locus of roots of $n$ equatinos in $Y \times \mathbb{A}^n$ given etale $f: X \to Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

We have $f: X \to Y$ an etale morphism of varieties (separated, irreducible, reduced scheme of finite type over $k$) over $k$, an algebraically closed field.
Why is $X$ locally the locus of roots of $n$ equations in $Y \times \mathbb{A}^n$ given etale $f: X \to Y$?

Given such $f$ we know: there exist affine opens $\operatorname{Spec}{A} = U \subseteq X$
and $\operatorname{Spec}{R} = V \subseteq Y$ with $x \in U$, corresponding to prime ideal $Q$, and $f(U) \subseteq V$ such that there exists a presentation
$A = R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$
with
$$
\det (\partial f_i / \partial X_j) + (f_1, \ldots, f_n) \notin Q.
$$

How do I see form this that $U$ is cut out by $n$ equations in $Y \times \mathbb{A}^n$? Thank you.

Comment: What you've written down in the "Given such $f$ we know..." paragraph is exactly the condition that $U$ is locally cut out by $n$ equations in $Y\times\Bbb A^n$. Can you be clearer about what you don't understand?

Comment: perhaps I had I misunderstood what it meant. Is it basically that $R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \cong   (R \otimes_k k[X_1, \ldots, X_n])/ (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, hence $U \cong \operatorname{Spec} R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \cong   (R \otimes_k k[X_1, \ldots, X_n])/ (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$?

Comment: Yes? I still don't understand your difficulty. Can you write out what you think "cut out by $n$ equations in $Y\times\Bbb A^n$" means, and why you're not sure that what you have meets this criteria?

Comment: I think it means that $U$ is isomorphic as a scheme over $k$ to an affine open subscheme of the form $\operatorname{Spec} T/ (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}T$ is an affine open subscheme of $Y \times_k \mathbb{A}^n_k$. If $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is an affine open subscheme of $Y$, then $\operatorname{SpecR \otimes_k k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]}$ is an affine open subscheme of  $Y \times_k \mathbb{A}^n_k$... I guess this is exactly what I wrote above. I get it now... Thank you!